# Regular extracting only time from the string

Tags: regex, time, loadrunner

Below is the string:

```
id='PMN_PRCSLIST_BEGINDTTM'>06/13/2018&nbsp; 6:35:00AM EDT</span>
```

From which i want to extract 6:35:00AM.
How do i achieve it using loadrunner?
I have tried doing:

```
id='PMN_PRCSLIST_BEGINDTTM'>(\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\dAM)</span>"
```

But it did not helped me.

Comment: Add `.*` after `BEGINDTTM'>` and after `AM)`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/8SY1DF/1

Comment: working like a charm! thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `.*` to match any chars in between `>` and the time, and between `AM` and `<`:

```
id='PMN_PRCSLIST_BEGINDTTM'>.* (\\d\\d?:\\d\\d:\\d\\d[AP]M).*</span>
```

Note you should add a space after the first `.*` since you may have 2 digits in the hour part and to match 1 or 2, you need `\d\d?`. To match `PM` or `AM`, use `[PA]M`.

Note that if the space before the time is optional, use lazy dot after `>`:

```
id='PMN_PRCSLIST_BEGINDTTM'>.*?(\\d\\d?:\\d\\d:\\d\\d[AP]M).*</span>
                              ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SY1DF/3)

Besides, if you want to stay within 1 tag value, replace `.*` with `[^<]*`.

Comment: How do i exclude "&nbsp;" from "06/13/2018&nbsp; 6:35:00AM EDT" and only capture "06/13/2018 6:35:00AM" @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @VishalCruise It is not possible to match discontinuous texts within 1 match operation, you need to post-process the match to either remove that substring or convert to the real space (&nbsp; is actually a non-breaking space).

Answer (score 0):

You have a far simpler path without regular expressions.   Check out the parameters for web_reg_save_param(_ex)

```
LB=id='PMN_PRCSLIST_BEGINDTTM'>
RB=</span>
SaveOffset=18
```